# How to get angle of point from center point?

Tags: python, trigonometry

If I have 2 points (x0,y0) which is the center of the circle, and another point (x,y) (this is the red dot on the circle boundary in the image). How can I get the angle of the dot?

Note, it should return an angle in degrees, from [0,360). The red dot angle in the image is approximately 70 degrees.

How can I do this in python?

Thanks

This doesn't seem to work.

```
        (dx, dy) = (x0-x, y-y0)
        angle = atan(float(dy)/float(dx))
        if angle < 0:
            angle += 180
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have dx flipped.  I think you're dx should be x-x0

Comment: My vote is for: redefining your x and y reference points so that it's on the x or y axis, thus always making the angle 0, 90, -90, or 180.

Comment: It looks like we're all on the right track here... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were very close :-)

Change this:

```
 angle = atan(float(dy)/float(dx))
```

To this:

```
 angle = degrees(atan2(float(dy), float(dx)))
```

The *atan2()* function is between than *atan()* because it considers the signs to the inputs and goes all the way around the circle:

```
atan2(...)
    atan2(y, x)

    Return the arc tangent (measured in radians) of y/x.
    Unlike atan(y/x), the signs of both x and y are considered
```

The *degrees()* function converts from radians to degrees:

```
degrees(...)
    degrees(x)

    Convert angle x from radians to degrees.
```

Also, as Rich and Cody pointed-out you need to fix your *dy* calculation.

Comment: Definitely better than my answer.  Just fix your arguments to `atan2`, and point out that the OP's `dy` calc is bad.

Comment: Minor edit I think atan2 requires 2 arguments.  Please correct me if I'm wrong...I think the "To this:" section, the dy should be the first argument, and the dy should be the second argument, if using math.atan2

Comment: Future readers of this post may find this URL useful: (section 9.2.3 trigonometric functions) https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

Answer (score 4):

In addition to converting from radians, consider using `atan2` instead of `atan`. Whereas `atan` will give the same answer for points on the opposite side of the circle, `atan2` will give you the correct angle, taking into account the signs of both `dx` and `dy`. It takes two arguments:

```
angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y0 - y, x0 - x)) % 360
```

Note that `atan2` will return something between `-pi` and `pi`, or -180 degrees and 180 degrees, so the `% 360` is to shift the result to your desired range.

Comment: Side comment: I love how sensibly Python defines `%` for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, easy mistake to make.  `atan` returns the value in **radians**, not **degrees**.  So you need to multiply the angle by `180/pi` to get it back to degrees.  You also need to change your `dy` to `y0 - y` to be consistent with your `dx`.  Here's some corrected code.

```
dx, dy = x0-x, y0-y
angle_in_radians = atan2(dy,dx) # you don't need to cast to float
angle_in_degrees = angle_in_radians * 180 / pi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float AnglePointToPoint(const CCPoint & pFrom, const CCPoint & pTo)
{
    float distanceX     = pTo.x - pFrom.x;
    float distanceY     = pTo.y - pFrom.y;
    float beta          = acos( fabs(distanceX) / sqrt( pow(distanceX,2) + pow(distanceY,2) ) ) * 180 / M_PI;
    float angleResult   = 0.0f;

    if( distanceX > 0 )
    {
        if( distanceY < 0 )
        {
            angleResult = beta + 90;//right_bot
        }
        else
        {
            angleResult = fabs(beta - 90);//right_top
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( distanceY < 0 )
        {
            angleResult = fabs(beta - 90) + 180;//left_bot
        }
        else
        {
            angleResult = beta + 270;//left_top
        }
    }
    return angleResult;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct formula if you need to find out the angle of a point in a Cartesian coordinate system, where positive Y is angle 0 and increases clockwise (e.g. negative X axis is 270 degrees), in case you end up here from a search. +1